# Store command output from openssl?

Tags: bash

Im writing a script where I'm trying to verify certificate passwords. This is what I had in mind.

```
passtest=$(openssl pkcs12 -info -in $CERTPATH -passin pass:$certpass)
if [[ $passtest == *"invalid password"* ]]; then
    NotOK
else
    Ok
fi
```

However, nothing is assigned to the $passtest variable. This approach works fine for other commands, but it seems like output from the openssl command is being directed somewhere else? The output it shown on screen when the script is run.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`openssl` reports errors on *stderr*. You have to redirect it to *stdout* first. This should work:

```
passtest=$(openssl pkcs12 -info -in $CERTPATH -passin pass:$certpass 2>&1)
```